# Error uploading Yii webpage to 000webhost.com

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to upload my web page created using Yii framework. I wanted to use a free hosting so I used 000webhost.com. When I uploaded the web page using FileZilla and to inserted the URL in the web browser I saw the following errors:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/username/public_html/../yii/framework/yii.php [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/index.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/username/public_html/../yii/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/username/public_html/index.php on line 12
```

I think that I should include Yii in the hosting but to be honest, I don't know how to do it.

Could somebody help me?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:**

My main menu is:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
```

And my structure folders is:

```
public_html/themes/verde/views/layout/main.php
public_html/protected/views/site/index
public_html/protected/views/site/contact
public_html/protected/views/site/login
public_html/protected/views/site/pages/about
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload the Yii framework to your webhost.
After that, make sure it's in the right directory. I though you can change the path in the index.php file.
(If you are sure you uploaded it to the right directory and still get errors, give the folder enough read / write access)

Comment: Thanks Stefan Koenen, now the problem is that I can't browse through the diferents tabs, I mean, I have: `<div id="mainmenu"> <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array( 'items'=>array(array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),...`And when I click in the tab the browser not found the webpage.

Comment: Maybe you can send a link to the website? The problem you describe doesn't make sence to me now.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this is the adress: http://pruebasubida.netii.net/ as you can see this is a very basic webpage, and the problem is that if you click on Home, about, etc, the browser doesn't find the page.

Comment: Sorry i can't help with this one, don't know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

do you have or had your app in a folder called site? you should go to protected/view/layouts and edit main.php to your correct links

```
<div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'xxx', 'url'=>array('xxx')),
                                     ...........
                                )
                        ))
```

you should have something similar to this. edit the 'url'=>array('xxx') to match the correct address

edit

locate your .htaccess in your public_html folder and put this in it (only this)

```
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

after that go to protected/config/main.php and in the components array put(or uncomment) this

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

that should fix your url problem.

Comment: Thanks Tavi. Yes, I have a folder called site inside protected/views/site, but I have the main.php inside the layer layout, and layout inside themes/verde/layout/main.php. The problem is that I don't know what should be the path, I mean the value of xxx in 'url'=>array('xxx') Could you help me?

Comment: so i guess your full path is something like /home/<username>/public_html/protected/ ? if so replace site/index.php whit <appname> index.php. if your protected folder is in /home/<username>/protected you don't need anything before the index.php. paths are a little tricky if your note used to linux type paths and file access. basically you need to replace site from the link whit the name of the controller (in case you are using controllers). please try to provide the whole <div id="mainmanu> in question and a map on how your filetree looks like

Comment: Tavi sorry but I don't udnerstand you, are you speaking about the path? I mean the "xxx" that you said before?

Comment: the actual path you uploaded the files to, when you open ftp, how does it look like? you probably open ftp and see a folder called public_html, what do you find it that folder? i was talking about the structure of the filesystem, you probably did something when uploading it, to different folder or subfolder that you didn't account for

Comment: Tavi I wrote my main menu and the structure of my folders in the main post. Thanks for helping me

Comment: where is your yii folder and what other folders do you have in public_html besides themes and protected?

Comment: Hi Tavi, public_html has assets, protected, themes and yii

Comment: were you developing your app on your own windows machine before uploading it to the hosting? i had a lot of trouble when uploading a web app developed on a windows machine. anyway my opinion is that the problem is your .htaccess file. if you look at the links on your page they look like this http://pruebasubida.netii.net/site/page.html?view=about   while they should look like http://pruebasubida.netii.net/index.php?r=site/page&view=about

Comment: so your problem is definetly .htaccess because if you try these links they "work" http://pruebasubida.netii.net/index.php/site/login   http://pruebasubida.netii.net/index.php/site/contact    http://pruebasubida.netii.net/index.php/site/page&view=about   but you have lots and lots of other errors around

Comment: Tavi I developed the web page before uploaded it, and everything worked, but as you can see, now the links doesn't work. Sorry but I don't understand what you want to tell me about the links. My links are the same when I use localhost. By the way, I used WAMP to develop the web page and I uncommented a line in the php.ini of the WAMP php, "extension=php_openssl.dll" to use sort urtl. Anyway, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't worry about the erros, I think that I can solve them, but I don't know how solve the problem in the .htaccess because I don't knwo what is the error.

Comment: read my edited answer, if that dosen't work i really have no other ideeas.

Comment: Thanks Tavi, I found the problem, in my 'urlManager' I had 'showScriptName'=>false, and I don't know what is the problem but this line doesn't work. I changed my .htacces with your code but the result was the same so I didn't remplace it, I only commented that line at 'urlManager' Do you know that this line doesn't work? THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: that array (urlManager) works just fine for me probably you have something else in your htaccess that rewrites it. you have find more documentation about urlManager here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url. good luck whit your first web app. you've chosen wisely yii framework, i just started whit it but i think its the best out there

Comment: Thanks Tavi, if I use the .htaccess that you told me and uncomment "urlSuffix" the problem continues so I think that maybe the problem is another thing. But for now at least the web page works well. Thanks for the documentation, I will try to find my mistake.